# abd emu geo fix <longitude> <latitude> is not working on Bitrise CI server

Tags: android, automation, continuous-integration, adb, bitrise

**Requirement**

We are required to conduct automated tests on a food delivery app which when launched it asks for permission to use the user's location and display a list of nearby restaurants.

**Problem**

When we run our tests on Bitrise the app fails to get the list of nearby restaurants because the CI server is in a different country.

**Attempted Solutions**

1. Added **"abd emu geo fix  "** to a script step in our Bitrise workflow right after creating and waiting for the emulator to launch
2. Tried to specify the name of the emulator by **"adb -s emulator-5554 emu geo fix  "**
3. Tried **"telnet localhost 5554"** where the connection gets established then directly gets closed **"connection closed by foreign host"**

**Investigations**

1. **"abd emu geo fix  "** works fine locally
2. **"telnet localhost 5554"** works fine locally

**Notes**

1. We are using Android 9.0 (API 28) both locally and on Bitrise
2. We are using JAVA 11 both locally and on Bitrise
3. We are using a Pixel emulator both locally and on Bitrise

Hope somebody could help us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had two solutions which are the following:

1. Add an **isAutomation** flag to the staging app so that when the flag is true the app always takes a static longitude and latitude and does not take the current location of the device.
2. Install a **VPN** on the server and specify the country we want, however, you should verify that the VPN has servers in the country you desire.

Eventually we went with the **isAutomation** flag workaround.